# Flex problems with horizontal and vertical alignments

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm experiencing some problems trying to align items (vertically and horizontally) in a Bootstrap card.

A = container that can vary of height in each card
B+C+D = 100% of the column

Vertical alignment needs:
B+C = align top
D = align bottom

Horizontal alignment needs:
C+D = has another flex with align in left and right

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5" style="border:1px solid green;">
                A
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-7 d-flex align-items-end flex-column">

                <div class="p-2" style="width:100%; border:1px solid green;">
                    B
                </div>
                
                <div class="p-2">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bd-highlight mb-3">
                        <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                            left
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                            right
                        </div>
                    </div>                        
                </div>

                <div class="mt-auto p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bd-highlight mb-3">
                        <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                            left
                        </div>
                        <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                            right
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I got this now: https://jsfiddle.net/sgn3atme/1/

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `align-items-end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `width: 100%` to `c-container` and `d-container` in your example.

```css
.c-container .c-wrapper:not(:last-child), .d-container .d-wrapper:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="card">
   <div class="card-body">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-5" style="border:1px solid green;">
         A
       </div>
       <div class="col-7 d-flex align-items-end flex-column">
          <div class="p-2 mb-3" style="width:100%; border:1px solid green;">
             B
          </div>
          <div class="p-2 w-100 mb-3 c-container" style="border:1px solid green;">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bd-highlight c-wrapper">
               <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                  left
               </div>
               <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                  right
               </div>
            </div>                        
          </div>
          <div class="mt-auto p-2 w-100 d-container" style="border:1px solid green;">
             <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bd-highlight d-wrapper">
               <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                 left
               </div>
             <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                 right
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `w-100` or `col-12` class in **C** & **D** (second parent of **left** & **right**) see the comments in the snippet below-

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5" style="border:1px solid green;">
                    A
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-7 d-flex align-items-end flex-column">

                    <div class="p-2" style="width:100%; border:1px solid green;">
                        B
                    </div>
                          <!-- used w-100 here -->
                    <div class="p-2 w-100 my-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bd-highlight my-2">
                            <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                                left
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                                right
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                  <!-- used col-12 here -->
                    <div class="mt-auto p-2 col-12" style="border:1px solid green;">
                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between bd-highlight my-2">
                            <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                                left
                            </div>
                            <div class="p-2" style="border:1px solid green;">
                                right
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```